# Output a new mp3 file from a lengthy mp3 mix which previews the audio at 5 different points of the mix

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I basically have a large collection of audio mix files in mp3 format, say approx 2 hours worth of music per mp3.

I am trying to work out the best way using the command line to output a preview MP3 file, this mp3 should have 5-10 second previews of the full mix at 6 or so points during the mix.

Example
00:00:10 - 00:00:20
00:30:00 - 00:30:10
00:50:00 - 00:50:10
...

So with the small mp3 file, you can kind of get an idea of the whole mix in a very short preview.

I have seen ffmpeg etc that can preview say 5 seconds up to 15 seconds of an audio, but not sure if this is capable of doing multiple points of the audio.

Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aselect filter in ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af aselect='between(t\,10\,20)+between(t\,1800\,1810)+between(t\,3000\,3010)' -c:v copy preview.mp3`

Each `between` block selects a time range. Times are expressed in seconds.

Comment: amazingly simple! Thank you